# Translating server code to ES6 using socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

We are complete newbies to socket.io and express. And we have followed along this tutorial to learn socket.io https://www.valentinog.com/blog/socket-react/

**And now we want to translate this line of code (older style):**

const index = require("./routes/index").default

**to ES6, below:**

import router from './routes/index'

app.use('/', router)

But it does not work for us. We get this error in the terminal.
[image: error]

**Full server.js code here**

```
import express from 'express'
const app = express()
import { createServer } from 'http'
const server = createServer(app)
import { Server } from "socket.io"
const io = new Server(server)
import cors from 'cors'

import router from './routes/index' 

const port = process.env.PORT || 4001

app.use('/', router)

app.use(index)

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

let interval

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("New client connected")
  if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval)
  } 
  interval = setInterval(() => getApiAndEmit(socket), 1000)
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected")
    clearInterval(interval)
  })
})

const getApiAndEmit = socket => {
  const response = new Date()

  socket.emit("FromAPI", response)
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Comment: You will probably have to modify how you export the routes. In your `routes/index` file, try replacing `module.exports = router;` by `export default router;`

Comment: Thanks, but we already did that.

Comment: In that case, please double-check the path, and try adding the extension of the file when `import`ing the file.

Comment: It's the extension (or lack thereof). You need to provide full file extensions with ESM. `import router from './routes/index.js'`. The error message even tells you this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use socket.io on my project like so:

```
const app = express()
const http = require('http').createServer(app)
const socketIo = require('socket.io')(http)
```

In other words I used require and did not use router. This might work for you unless there is a specific reason you need to do otherwise.

Comment: Did you only go with require and never used import in your code?

Comment: @Caroline No I usually used import but it seems I specifically used the require method for those packages.

Comment: Our problem seems to be that we can not use a mix of import and require in the same server.js file - that makes the server not run at all. Therefore we tried our best to translate the code relating to socket.io to ES6 but we did not get all the way there yet.

Comment: @William `require` is not an ES6 import. It's CJS, and won't work in an ESM environment.